# Notification for host failure and health status

Tags: mongodb, failover

I set up a MongoDB cluster with replica sets.

I wish to have something like a dashboard or a "health status". My current solution is to connect to the cluster and query the replication state once in a while.

How can I find out that a host failed or get the health status of the cluster?

I already searched for solutions and found solutions like this:
[Percona Monitoring and Management](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management) but it considers performance metrics rather than failover related information.

Comment: It's a good question, I don't know of any tool, more than connecting using a GUI like Compass, where you can see it visually. And think about [asking in the developers forum](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/).

Comment: In case you're using Atlas, check Project>Integrations